# What is the correct format for adding a message history in Pipedream with OpenAI?

Tags: openai-api, pipedream

Integrating pipedream with openai:
I am using pipedream with openai, and in the option to put in "Prior Message History", nothing I put in works.

I have tried the following:

`[{"role":"user","content":"Hello"},{"role":"assistant","content":"Hello! How can I assist you today?"}]`

and I received the following error

> "Configuration error The following message doesn't have a "role"
> property:
>
> "[{"role":"user","content":"Hello"},{"role":"assistant","content":"Hello!
> How can I assist you today?"}]"

I have also tried:

```
messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"},
    {"role": "assistant", "content": "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?"}
]
```

and I receive an error "Please provide a valid array of chat messages."

Comment: There is a backtick character is that in the real code?

Comment: No, my question was edited and that was left in.